# Using toast inside timertask

Tags: android

Found someone has similar issue online [here](http://ranger1976.blogspot.com/2009/04/cant-make-toast-from-timertask-while.html).

This doesn't work:

```
Timer t = new Timer(false);
t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
@Override
public void run() {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "msg", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}, 5000);
```

But if I instantiate the toast outside the timertask then show it inside `run`,it works.

I think it may relate to the so-called UI thread,

but how exactly ?

Comment: You cannot use Toast or make any UI updates from a non UI-thread.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad, any more details?

Comment: look at the end of [this page](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html), specially where it says: `Make sure that you access the Android UI toolkit only on the UI thread.`

Comment: @Eng.Fouad,I'm seeking of more internal reason

Answer (score 9):

try this

```
Timer t = new Timer(false);
t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
@Override
public void run() {
       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "msg", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: I know there're several ways to make it work,but I just don't know why the original way does NOT work, and why it works if toast is created outside.

Comment: Almost perfect, but you shouldn't be using the ApplicationContext for a Toast, you should be using the Activity.

Answer (score 1):

Using Timer starts a new thread, I suppose that thread does not have access to `getApplicationContext`. The proper way to do it is to use `Handler` and call the `postDelayed` method of the Handler - which does not start a new thread.

Read about this: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html

The link you posted has a working example, which is the proper way to do it:

```
final Context ctx = this;
Handler mHandler = new Handler();

Runnable
makeToast = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "msg", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};
mHandler.postDelayed(makeToast, 1000);
```

Comment: I also tried `ActivityClassName.this`, it also doesn't work, why?

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you start an application, it starts on the UI Thread (also called the Main Thread).

Whenever you create a new Thread, or Timer, or AsyncTask, by definition, they're creating new Threads.  Threads that aren't the main thread simply don't have permission to modify the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Toast use on UIThread. You can by Handler or runOnUiThread