# how to display a textview for few seconds and then make it invisible?

Tags: android

this website is the best, its help me a lot ...I am a beginner in creating android applecation .
this is my first time I ask a question here.. my question is how to display a textview just for 5 seconds and the make it disappear.. when I search I found some codes but I didnt know how to use it or maybe I use it in wrong way.. so can anyone give me a very simple example how to do it please??
I really will appreciate your help......>>(I dont want the text to disappear, I want the hole textview to disappear)

Comment: You could use an AsyncTask to remove the TextView from the layout.  Maybe post the code you tried, and describe how it's failing?

Comment: If it's just to show the User some kind of information like 'foobar deleted' or the like, you can use the `Toast` class.

Comment: TextView txt= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);

     TimerTask task = new TimerTask() { 

     @Override 
     public void run() { 
     txt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

     } 
     }; 
     Timer timer = new Timer(); 
     timer.schedule(task, 5000); 
   
when I write this code after 5 seconds the app stop ..you know this messege "ufortanately the app as stopped">> I hate it .. I think I did something wrong

Comment: Its hard to see exactly what you have with the code in comments but try my updated example with `TimerTask`. That should work for you. And declare your `TextView` as a member variable (Declare it before `onCreate()` but initialize it inside `onCreate()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way would be to use a [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) if you want the timer to show

```
public void onCreate(...){
...
timer = new MyCountDown(5000, 1000);
}

private class MyCountDown extends CountDownTimer
{
    long duration, interval;
    public MyCountDown(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        textView1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);    
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long duration) { 
             // could set text for a timer here     
    }   
}
```

You also could use a [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html).

[Here is a SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352259/using-toast-inside-timertask) with a good example of `TimerTask`

There are also various other ways. You can search through the Docs or SO to decide which best suits your needs

**Edit with `TimerTask` example**

```
  Timer t = new Timer(false);
  t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                txt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 12):

Using AsyncTask:

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>()
{

  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
  {
    Thread.sleep(5000);                   // sleep 5 seconds
  }

  protected void onPostExecute (Void result)
  {
    // fade out view nicely
    AlphaAnimation alphaAnim = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f,0.0f);
    alphaAnim.setDuration(400);
    alphaAnim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener()
    {
     public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
     {
       // make invisible when animation completes, you could also remove the view from the layout
       myTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
     }
    });

    myTextView.startAnimation(alphaAnim);


  }
}.execute();
```

Or, better yet, just use animation:

EDITED (thanks @pkk for suggestion):

```
// fade out view nicely after 5 seconds
AlphaAnimation alphaAnim = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f,0.0f);
alphaAnim.setStartOffset(5000);                        // start in 5 seconds
alphaAnim.setDuration(400);
alphaAnim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener()
{
 public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
 {
   // make invisible when animation completes, you could also remove the view from the layout
   myTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
 }
});

myTextView.setAnimation(alphaAnim);
```

Comment: Why did you change your answer? I liked the 'Animation-only' solution much better.

Comment: Really cool solution with the only - animation approach. However (at least on api 14), two lines of the example above need to be changed:
`alphaAnim.setStartTime(5000);  // to alphaAnim.setStartOffset(5000);
// ...
myTextView.startAnimation(alphaAnim);  // to myTextView.setAnimation(alphaAnim);
`
Without this, the animation starts immediately.

Answer (score 3):

```
        final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        // add textView on some Layout
        textView.setText("Text or smth. from resource");        
        CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

                        @Override
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFinish() {
                            textView .setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //(or GONE)
                            }
                    }.start();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Handler with runnable to do this.
Like i am doing for according my need.

I have a Activity1 from where i am going to Activity2 to update profile after updating profile i have to show a "Update Successfully" text in the Activity1 so i am creating a flag "PERSONAL_DETAIL_UPDATE" in the AppConstants and setting it "true" when profile update success in Activity2 and calling the Activity1 from there to show updated profile to user.

Now in the Activity2 using this code to i am showing "Update Successfully" text for 3 seconds and after 3 seconds making it gone.
I am making the visibility of TextView gone by default in xml for this code you can modify according to your need.

```
enter code here



 if (AppConstants.PERSONAL_DETAIL_UPDATE) {
        personalDetailUpdateSuccessTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                personalDetailUpdateSuccessTV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }, 3000);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and a [Runnable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html) to do this.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private Handler h;
TextView txt;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
    Runnable r=new Runnable(){

        @Override 
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e("bf", "fd");
            h.postDelayed(this, 500);
            if (txt.isShown()){
                txt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }
            else{
                txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

    };
    h=new Handler();
    h.post(r);
}
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CounDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer) for this

```
if (password.text.toString() == preferences.getPassword()) {
            textView.text = ""
            endLockScreen.finishLockScreen()

        } else {
            textView.text = "Wrong Password"
            val timer = object : CountDownTimer(1000, 1000) {
                override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {}
                override fun onFinish() {
                    textView.text = ""
                }
            }.start()
        }
```